# Open the algorithm dialog of a custom QgsProcessingAlgorithm instance

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

In a custom plugin I'm calling some custom `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` that are loaded with the plugin itself.

If I create an instance of these algorithms I need to prefill the parameters with some custom values and I think this can easily be done by passing a custom dictionary to the `initAlgorithm` method [0].

I'm setting some *side* variables needed by be plugin (that have not to be outputs), but again this can be done by setting some class variables (i.e. `self.my_custom_id = 'zzz'`) and getting them when needed.

```
my_algorithm = MyCustomAlgorithm()
my_algorithm.initAlgorithm(
    'INPUT': 'custom_path'
)
# how to open and exec the algorithm dialog?
```

What I'm not able to do is to simply open/exec the algorithm dialog.

If I use `processing.createAlgorithmDialog` then I can exec the algorithm dialog but I cannot retrieve the *side* variables needed.

```
my_dialog = processing.createAlgorithmDialog(
    'my_custom_provider:my_custom_algorithm`,
    {
    'INPUT': 'custom_path'
    }
)
my_dialog.exec_()
```

I'm stuck in this loop. Somebody has already faced the same issue?

[0] https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingAlgorithm.initAlgorithm

Answer (score 1):

In your second approach you could use the [`algorithm()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/Processing/QgsProcessingAlgorithmDialogBase.html#qgis.gui.QgsProcessingAlgorithmDialogBase.algorithm) method to retrieve the instance of your custom `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` and then access its class variables.

```
my_dialog = processing.createAlgorithmDialog(
    'my_custom_provider:my_custom_algorithm',
    {
        'INPUT': 'custom_path'
    }
)

# access your custom class variables
print(my_dialog.algorithm().my_custom_id) # prints 'zzz'

my_dialog.exec()
```

`createAlgorithmDialog` can also receive an instance of `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` as first argument to create a dialog. Therefore the following will also be a valid option:

```
my_algorithm = MyCustomAlgorithm()
my_dialog = processing.createAlgorithmDialog(
    my_algorithm,
    {
        'INPUT': 'custom_path'
    }
)
# access your custom class variables
print(my_algorithm.my_custom_id) # prints 'zzz'
# execute dialog
my_dialog.exec()
```

Comment: thanks! No idea why but my QGIS (doesn't matter which version 3.22, 3.26, 3.27) is crashing if I make an instance of my algorithm and pass it to the `createAlgorithmDialog` method. Anyway, I can use the unique identifier. I also discovered that you have access to the resuls with `my_dialog.results()` after the execution.